# How to add "contact us for shipping quote" for certain items?

Tags: shipping

I have a heap of shipping rules set up, based on weight which accounts for 95% of the stock on the site, but there are a handful of items which are large, and unusual sizes, so would need to have their shipping calculated manually.

How can I add an option, where the weight is say 0, to show "please contact us for shipping quote" instead of adding a shipping option, and disable the online purchase option?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do this with a weight of 0, because that's also used for free shipping promotions.

You either need to get a custom carrier in here or what some people do is set a very high rate and then ensure that the rules (I assume you are using table rates) will not match. It will then show the default error message if enabled.

There are other solutions such as cart2quote.